# Select column from group using linq

Tags: c#, linq

LinqToSQL I am having a problem to select a column from a group, below is my query

```
var qry = (from i in INTERNETDATAs 
join c in COVERS on Convert.ToInt32(i.COVERTYPE) equals c.COV_TYPE
join b in BENEFITS on c.COVERID equals b.COVERID
join p in POLICies on i.REFERENCENO equals p.BACS_POLNO into grp
    where  i.DATELOADED >= new DateTime(2013,1,1)
    && i.DATELOADED < new DateTime(2014,1,1)
    && i.CAMPAIGNTYPE == "1"
    && c.COVERTYPEID == 17063789
orderby i.DOB   
select new
{
    i.ID,
    Campaign = i.CAMPAIGNTYPE,
    Title = i.TITLE,
    Dob = i.DOB,
    Accepted = i.ACCEPTED,
    BankLetter = i.BANKLETTER,
    //p.STATUS,
    //grp.STATUS,
    MonthlyPremium = c.MONTHLYPREMIUM,
    BenefitAmount = b.BENEFITAMOUNT,
    Description = b.BENEFITDESCRIPTION
}
).DefaultIfEmpty();         

 qry.Dump();
```

This query gives expected result but I also need a `STATUS` column from `POLICies` table, when I remove the comment for `//p.STATUS` or `//grp.STATUS` I get following Error as below

Cannot execute text selection:

> 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' does not
>   contain a definition for 'STATUS' and no extension method 'STATUS'
>   accepting a first argument of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' could be
>   found (press F4 to add a using directive or assembly reference)

If any one can please help me out with this as I have tried everything I can.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are group joining `POLICIES` by their `BACS_POLNO` field, think of it as `group by` in SQL. In the final selector, `grp` is actually a collection of grouped items and each of them can potentially have a different `BACS_POLNO` value.

If you want to produce separate items for every distinct `BACS_POLNO`, perform a regular join:

```
join p in POLICies on i.REFERENCENO equals p.BACS_POLNO
```

Or you could, for instance, just select the first `BACS_POLNO` from the grouped collection:

```
var qry = (from i in INTERNETDATAs 
join c in COVERS on Convert.ToInt32(i.COVERTYPE) equals c.COV_TYPE
join b in BENEFITS on c.COVERID equals b.COVERID
join p in POLICies on i.REFERENCENO equals p.BACS_POLNO into grp
    where  i.DATELOADED >= new DateTime(2013,1,1)
    && i.DATELOADED < new DateTime(2014,1,1)
    && i.CAMPAIGNTYPE == "1"
    && c.COVERTYPEID == 17063789
orderby i.DOB   
select new
{
    i.ID,
    Campaign = i.CAMPAIGNTYPE,
    Title = i.TITLE,
    Dob = i.DOB,
    Accepted = i.ACCEPTED,
    BankLetter = i.BANKLETTER,
    grp.First().STATUS,
    MonthlyPremium = c.MONTHLYPREMIUM,
    BenefitAmount = b.BENEFITAMOUNT,
    Description = b.BENEFITDESCRIPTION
}
).DefaultIfEmpty();
```